In Firefox DevTools Network tab, how to see only failed requests?
I want to be able to see all requests that have error responses (of any kind). By that, I mean requests that have a response with a status code like "4xx" or "5xx".
I discovered that I can type status-code:200 into the search bar to get only successful requests (that aren't redirects), but I can't type that in for all errors (because there are many error codes).

Those are error responses, not requests.

@Dai you're right; I've adjusted the wording to clarify that.

Firefox's manual describes a [-]status-code:n filter you can use in the Network tab, though it only supports filtering-only (or filtering-out-only) individual codes (rather than ranges).
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/request_list/#filtering-by-properties
In my experience, it's probably easier to filter-out known good responses so that all other responses: including errors and unexpected/unusual status-codes, remain; so you'll need something like this:
-status-code:200 -status-code:201 -status-code:204 -status-code:300 -status-code:301 -status-code:302 -status-code:303 -status-code:304

Note that Firefox will filter-out failed requests that were blocked by filters/extensions with, for example, the -status-code:200 and -status-code:204 filters, despite the lack of a green mark in the HTTP Status column.
Before:

After:

